# iText7 - How to obtain image object data

Tags: c#, itext7

I need to add a `BarcodeQRCode` image to a `PdfCanvas` but I have not found how to do it.

I have the following code

```
BarcodeQRCode qr;
PdfFormXObject xObject;
Image im;

PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);

qr = new BarcodeQRCode(msg);
xObject = qr.CreateFormXObject(Color.BLACK, _pdfDoc);
im = new Image(xObject);
im.SetFixedPosition(10f, 10f);
```

At this point I need to add the image object to the canvas, but in iText7 I need to pass the image object like a iText.IO.Image.ImageData, and that's the problem, because to make this I need the Byte[] of the image.

My question is, How to obtain the Byte[] of the Image object?

I have also tried to do this to obtain the ImageData

```
PdfImageXObject xoi;
xoi = new PdfImageXObject(xObject.GetPdfObject());
iText.IO.Image.ImageData id = iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create(xoi.GetImageBytes());
```

but I take an error, because `xoi.GetImageBytes()` throws a null reference exception. Is like the PdfImageXObject is not created correctly.

I am a Little crazy and I need help, please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to pass the `ImageData` object in iText7 in order to draw on `PdfCanvas`. `ImageData` is for common images (PNG, JPG), but for barcodes you don't want to lose quality and there are other ways of adding a barcode to the canvas.

In your case, you have already created a `PdfFormXObject` instance and you can add it to the canvas with `PdfCanvas#addXObject` as follows:

```
BarcodeQRCode barcode = new BarcodeQRCode(messageText);
PdfFormXObject barcodeFormXObject = barcode.createFormXObject(Color.BLACK, document);

float scale = 5;
float x = 10;
float y = 10;
canvas.addXObject(barcodeFormXObject, scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
```

**UPD**: In order for the barcode to be of fixed size regardless of its contents, you can use the following code:

```
// Tweak this value for fixed width and height
float fixedWidthAndHeight = 300;
float formXobjectWidthAndHeight = barcodeFormXObject.getHeight();
float scale = fixedWidthAndHeight / formXobjectWidthAndHeight;
float x = 10;
float y = 10;
canvas.addXObject(barcodeFormXObject, scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);
```

Please note that some padding is added to the barcode, so its width/height will not be equal to `fixedWidthAndHeight` if you measure the distance between two opposite black squares, but it will be proportional to `fixedWidthAndHeight`, so you can tweak this variable as needed.

Comment: What do you mean by the same problem? Previous problem was that you didn't know how to add a barcode to the canvas properly, now that you know how to do that, how come the problem be the same? Please describe your problem properly by editing the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

It is one of the options that I tried, but I have the same problem that I had with the use of modulesize in the call to barcode.createFormXObject (Color.BLACK, modulesize, document); and is that I can not control a fixed escalation, I mean, to be able to determine that the resulting image has a fixed dimension.

Comment: The problem is that the size of the image that the BarcodeQRCode generates varies according to its content, the greater the content, the resulting image is larger, for that reason a scale can not be fixed, since it would have to be calculated according to the size from image.

In summary, what I am looking for is to be able to scale the image to a fixed dimension to add it to the canvas, regardless of its content, since it is variable.

Possibly my problem with this would be also not knowing how to calculate that fixed scale.

Comment: Again, thanks for your response and if you have any suggestions for solving this, I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: sorry for my terrible English and for making a mistake in putting the first message.

Comment: In your example, the size of the resulting image depends on the content of the QR, so even if you put a scale of 5, the size varies and I need it to be fixed.

Comment: Ok, I get what your goal is. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @mduran16, please take a look at the update in my answer.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!
Your are my King.

You have solved my problem.

Comment: @mduran16 It is custom to accept an answer if it solved the problem. Please check the checkmark under the score of the answer.